# How to pass Data from JSP File to droplet using Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, atg

I want to pass data from jsp file to droplet using ajax.

```
function myNotification(productId,skuId,product) {
     if (confirm('Are you sure?')) { 
     $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "merchant_popup.jsp",
            data : {
                productId:""+productId+"",
                skuId : "" + skuId + "",
                product : "" + product + "",

            },
            success : function(result) {
                if(result.trim() == "OK"){
                    alert("Email send successfully");
                } else {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            }//
        });

     }else{
     }
 }
```

Then I use below droplet to catch data within merchant_popup.jsp

merchant_popup.jsp

```
            <dsp:droplet name="EmailNotification">
                <dsp:param name="productId" param="productId" />
                <dsp:param name="skuId" param="skuId" />                    
                <dsp:param name="product" param="product" />

            </dsp:droplet>
```

But function is not success. Can any one help me.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNBni.png)

Comment: If the request isn't successful you should be seeing an error in the console. Please check it and let us know what it says

Comment: Also note that you don't need to append empty strings to you variables. `productId: productId,` etc. will work fine

Comment: is `merchant_popup.jsp` on the same directory ?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan it gives pop up with message "Error".

Comment: @Mr.Developer Yes merchant_popup.jsp on the same directory

Comment: @Lankani that means that `result.trim()` is not `== 'OK'`. Debug what it is.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It gives an empty page as result..

Comment: In that case you need to debug your server code to see why it returns nothing

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thank you very much. I,m new for the field. I'll try my best. But I have a question. Is this data pass to the merchant_popup.jsp?

Answer (score 0):

If merchant_popup.jsp is in same folder , and dsp:import for the droplet mentioned is available ..Path Of/EmailNotification. Try adding some dummy statement with dsp:valueof for param::

```
enter code here
```

See if these values are going till JSP or not.

I believe there might be three possibilities. I am not sure where you are stuck.

1. The way you are posting value. Try below way.

```js
data : {  
              "productId" : productId,
              "skuId" : skuId,
              "product" : product,
               },
```

2. Droplet is not imported or properly not imported (path of component).
3. If values are passing and in droplet you are able to get the passed data then,
   Please check the droplet response. are you really setting correctly response.redirect, or checkRedirect parameters in droplet with "OK" as string.
4. If third one is not correctly done then  should give you some value.

Try above step by step. to avoid turn around time work directly on .jsp in .ear file in development mode.

Thanks,
hope it helps..!! 
Cheers..!!